# Como lincar um variável de uma classe em c++ em lua script?

Tags: c, c++, lua

Como faço para acessar e setar uma variável de uma classe feita em C++ passa para Lua?

```
// C++
#ifndef SCRIPTSTORAGE_H
#define SCRIPTSTORAGE_H

#include "HTest.h"

#include <luajit/lua.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct HObject {
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
    float x, y, z;
    float sx, sy, sz;
    float u, v;

    HObject()
    {
        id = 1;
    }
};

static bool checkFunctionArgs(lua_State* ls, const char* fname, unsigned int nargs)
{
    int fnargs = lua_gettop(ls) - 1;

    if(fnargs < (int)nargs)
    {
        std::cout << "LuaScriptError: " << fname << "() need at least %d parameter(" << nargs << ")\n" << std::endl;;
        return true;
    }

    if(fnargs > (int)nargs)
    {
        std::cout << "LuaScriptError: " << fname << "() takes " << nargs << " positional arguments but " << fnargs << " were given" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

HObject* HObject_check(lua_State* ls, int index)
{
    void* ud = 0;

    luaL_checktype(ls, index, LUA_TTABLE);
    lua_getfield(ls, index, "__self");

    ud = luaL_checkudata(ls, index, "HObject:new");

    luaL_argcheck(ls, ud != 0, 0, "'HObject:new' expected");

    return *((HObject**)ud);
}

static int HObject_newHObject(lua_State* ls)
{
    if(checkFunctionArgs(ls, "HObjec:new", 0)){
        return 0;
    }

    luaL_checktype(ls, 1, LUA_TTABLE);
    lua_newtable(ls);

    lua_pushvalue(ls, 1);
    lua_setmetatable(ls, -2);

    lua_pushvalue(ls, 1);
    lua_setfield(ls, 1, "__index");

    HObject** obj = (HObject**)lua_newuserdata(ls, sizeof(HObject*));
    *obj = new HObject();

    luaL_getmetatable(ls, "HObject:new");
    lua_setmetatable(ls, -2);

    lua_setfield(ls, -2, "__self");

    return 1;
}

static int HObject_destructor(lua_State* ls)
{
    HObject* obj = HObject_check(ls, 1);
    delete obj;

    return 1;
}

void HTest_register(lua_State* ls)
{
    static const luaL_Reg hobjec_funcs[] = {
        {"new", HObject_newHObject},
        {"__gc", HObject_destructor},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    luaL_newmetatable(ls, "HObject:new");
    luaL_register(ls, 0, hobjec_funcs);
    lua_pushvalue(ls, -1);
    lua_setfield(ls, -2, "__index");

    luaL_register(ls, "HObject", hobjec_funcs);
}

#endif // SCRIPTSTORAGE_H


-- Lua
local obj = HObject:new() -- OK

obj.variavel = 10 -- Exemplo de escrever na variável
print(obj.variavel) -- Exemplo de acessar variável
```

Eu quero acessar e escrever na variável, mas não sei como lincar o mesmo em Lua. Já consegui lincar a classe `HOBject` junto com suas funções, só faltam as variáveis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe forma padrão de estabelecer acesso de variáveis em LUA. Tu tens duas opções para contornar isto:

## Getter and Setters

A primeira é mais fácil, mas pode parecer meio feia. Tu pode criar getters e setters. Assim você teria que criar um par get e set para cada variável que você deseja ter acessível, por exemplo:

```
static int getVariavel(lua_State* ls)
{
    //Obter seu objeto aqui
    lua_pushinteger(ls, obj->variavel);
    return 1;
}
static int setVariavel(lua_State* ls)
{
    //Obter seu objeto aqui
    obj->variavel = lua_tointeger(ls, -1);
    lua_pop(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Você tem que criar um par desses para cada variável, mas isso pode ser simplificado com a ajuda de macros e/ou templates. Com este modelo você pode acessar e alterar as variáveis da seguinte forma:

```
local obj = HObject:new() -- OK
obj:setVariavel(10) -- Exemplo de escrever na variável
print(obj:getVariavel()) -- Exemplo de acessar variável
```

## Filtrando por `__index` `__newindex`

A outra forma seria colocar handlers para os eventos `__index` e `__newindex` na metatable dos objetos. Assim, tu poderia filtrar os nomes das variáveis e devolver seus valores:

```
static int index(lua_State *ls)
{
    ///Obter objeto aqui.
    string s = lua_tostring(ls, 2);
    if(s == "variavel")
        lua_pushinteger(ls, obj->variavel);
    else if(s == "variavel2")
        lua_pushinteger(ls, obj->variavel2);
    // Outras variáveis aqui.
    else
    {
        //Chamar a table com as funções.
    }
    return 1;
}
static int newIndex(lua_State *ls)
{
    //Obter objeto aqui
    string s = lua_tostring(ls, 2);
    if(s == "variavel")
        obj->variavel = lua_tointeger(ls, -1);
    else if(s == "variavel2")
        obj->variavel2 = lua_tointeger(ls, -1);
    //..outras variáveis aqui.
    else
        //Mostrar msg de erro dizendo que tal variável não existe.
}
```

Este modelo precisa apenas destas duas funções, mas comparar as strings uma a uma pode ser lento se tiver um número muito grande de atributos e sua class. Por outro lado, o acesso em Lua fica mais bonito, em minha opinião:

```
-- Lua
local obj = HObject:new() -- OK

obj.variavel = 10 -- Exemplo de escrever na variável
print(obj.variavel) -- Exemplo de acessar variável
```

Comment: TalesM, obrigado pela resposta. Eu fiz com getter e setter mesmo :/. Mas como sera que isso é feito em LuaBind por exemplo?

Comment: Eu não conheço muito do LuaBind, mas sei que ele automatiza muita coisa, usando templates. Mas por baixo disso tudo ele chama a API da Lua, então deve implementar uma dessas técnicas por debaixo dos panos.